# Using any_instance and should_receive together is not working

Tags: rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

Simplifying my problem:

```
  it 'should call resolve', focus: true do
    SubscriptionEventResolver.any_instance.should_receive(:resolve)
    SubscriptionEventResolver.new(double().as_null_object).resolve
  end
```

This test fails with the following message:

```
Failures:

  1) SubscriptionEvent should call resolve
     Failure/Error: SubscriptionEventResolver.any_instance.should_receive(:resolve)
       (#<Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x007f89c40a5488>).resolve(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/models/subscription_event_spec.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.44287 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Why?

(I'm using  rspec-rails (2.14.0) with all dependencies updated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

class SubscriptionEventResolver < Struct.new(:event)
end

describe SubscriptionEventResolver do
  it 'should call resolve' do
    SubscriptionEventResolver.any_instance.should_receive(:resolve)
    SubscriptionEventResolver.new(double().as_null_object).resolve
  end
end
```

gives me

```
[17:40] arkham ~/Desktop [2.0.0-p247]
↳ $ ruby resolver_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.0011 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Maybe there is something else interfering?

Comment: You are right, excluding my app environment entirely makes this test pass. Any clue on where to look at?

Comment: I've seen that the error tells something about mocha, could it be that the test is using mocha's any_instance instead of rspec's one?

Comment: I can see Mocha is being required by shoulda-matchers gem which I didn't notice at first. Thanks for pointing out. I'm marking this as the correct answer because you headed me in the right direction.

Comment: To be more precise, for future readers, my problem was the shuolda-matchers gem not being up to date. Updating from 1.4.2 to 2.4.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
it 'should call resolve', focus: true do
  resolver = double('resolver')
  resolver.should_receive(:resolve)
  SubscriptionEventResolver.stub(:new).and_return(resolver)

  SubscriptionEventResolver.new(double('argument').as_null_object).resolve
end
```